# Как запланировать сообщение в aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Админ указывает время и сообщение, когда нужно отправить всем участникам бота. Как запланировать сообщение?

```py
router = Router()


@router.message(Command(commands=["notification"]))
async def notification(message: types.Message,
                       state: FSMContext) -> None:
    await message.answer(text="Time")
    await state.set_state(States.time)


@router.message(States.time)
async def time_notification(message: types.Message,
                            state: FSMContext) -> None:
    await message.answer("Text")
    await state.update_data(time=message.text)
    await state.set_state(States.time)


@router.message(States.notification)
async def send_notification(message: types.Message,
                            state: FSMContext,
                            dao: DataAccessObject) -> None:
    users = await dao.get_all_users()
    data = await state.get_data()
    await state.clear()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1517823/470333 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1521371/470333